# How to ping a remote server(with public ip) from a local machine?

Tags: networking, remote-access, remote-server, ntp

I have a board in office with ip `192.168.20.x`. I have `vpn` access to the office from my laptop with `public ip`.

I'm able to `ping` the board, but what should I do to `ping` my laptop from the board?

I am running a `ntp` server on my machine, so that the time will be in sync with my laptop.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop should get an IP address from the virtual VPN adapter. Try to use this address when doing reverse ping. You can see all adapters and IP addresses in your PC using console command `ipconfig` assuming you are on windows.